# Shares size in header

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add this line

```
static CGFloat maxTextHeight =  90;
```

In Header of MyClass and I want use it from any classes. Then I do it I have compilers notification that it not used. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use extern like this:

```
// in .h
extern CGFloat const maxTextHeight; 

// in .m
CGFloat const maxTextHeight =  90.0;
```

Comment: Yes.  In fact, doing so is common for scalar types.

Comment: You only put the .m code in the one module that is the "home" module.

Comment: If it's a constant it's probably best done as a #define or some other sort of declared constant.